# How to stop locationManager pendingIntent updates from a service, when the locationManager was started from an activity that's been swiped closed?

Tags: java, android, service, locationmanager

I have an activity that starts up locationManager.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("myBroadcast");
    intent.putExtra("session_id", session_id);
    intent.putExtra("device_id", device_id);
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    lpendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity.getApplicationContext(), 58534, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //Register for broadcast intents
    locationManager  = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 0, lpendingIntent);
```

A broadcastReceiver gets this intent and starts a service.

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
//private static boolean semaphore = true;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Location location = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);

    Intent locationServiceIntent = new Intent(context, DistanceFilterLocationService.class);
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("device_id", intent.getStringExtra("device_id"));
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("session_id", intent.getStringExtra("session_id"));

     Double longi = location.getLongitude();
     Double lati = location.getLatitude();

    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("longitude", longi);
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("latitude", lati);
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("accuracy", location.getAccuracy());
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("time", location.getTime());
    //context.unregisterReceiver(this);
    context.startService(locationServiceIntent);


}
```

}

The service starts and kills itself nicely.  I can unregister my broadcast receiver easy enough, but how do I stop the pendingIntent from continually pinging gps even though no broadcastreceiver is there to receive it?  My service can't seem to see the pendingIntent from the activity as the activity has been swiped closed, so I can't call removeUpdates(pendingIntent);